# Display pdf documents in java using iText (and not acrobat reader)?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I can get the the file to open and display in an external reader but it is possible to get it to open within java (eg. in a JPanel)? I am using iText would this be possible or would i need something like ICEPdf?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, you can use pdfRender to render PDFs as images, so that you can view them

Comment: Dammit, you're right, pdfRender is so new that I didn't think about it! :-D

Comment: Yes that is possible. But it also depends what you want to support. Easiest solution would be to convert each page to an image and display it inside a jframe. You need to implement some kind of page scrolling etc. But when you want to support other features like form fields, annotations, different layers, attachments, signature support it will quickly get more complicated and results in higher effort. So you need to carefully weight what you want and need. There are already such solutions. E.g. the old [jpedal](https://github.com/Lonzak/JPedal) for instance supported that out of the box.